# Where should I set UINavigationController's delegate property?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working with some custom controller transitions, which make use of UINavigationController's `delegate` property. If I set it in `viewDidLoad()`, `self.navigationController?.delegate` gets deallocated at some point after the push. Setting it in `viewWillAppear()` works, but I'm wondering why that property gets deallocated in the first place, and where people typically set this property.

```
    // The first time you push, it will work correctly, and the delegate function below is called. After you pop back to this controller, delegate is nil (has been deallocated)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    // Brute force works
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
                              from fromVC: UIViewController,
                              to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        if operation == .push {
            return WTPPushAnimator()
        }
        if operation == .pop {
            return WTPPopAnimator()
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: no answer still? I see the close problem, that is not going to be deallocated, but delegate methods didn't fire :(

Comment: seems like it happens when u call navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false) instead navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

If the `ViewController` you are pushing also sets `navigationController?.delegate = self`, then when that `ViewController` is popped, that `ViewController` will be deallocated and the `weak var delegate` will be set to `nil`.  `viewDidLoad()` only runs when the `ViewController` is first created, so when returning to the first `ViewController`, `viewDidLoad()` will not run again. `viewWillAppear()` is always called when a `ViewController` is pushed or when it is returned to on a pop, so `viewWillAppear()` is the right place to set this `delegate`.

Comment: It's not being popped though. It is the root controller of the NavigationController.

Comment: I'd suggest setting a watch breakpoint on the delegate value to find out who is setting it back to nil.

Comment: You can write an extension for `UINavigationController` delegate property and call super implementation inside.